# header not revealing the ip address?

Tags: node.js, header, koa

```
{ host: '127.0.0.1:8080',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36',
  accept: '*/*',
  referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  cookie: 'io=bP2eXrqS3SkWYY4cAAAC11' }
```

I am using koa.io from npm to try and get the ip address of the client connecting. when I try the following code the above is printed in the console. I can't seem to get the ip address of the client.

```
app.io.use(function* userLeft(next) {
    // on connect
    console.log(this.headers);
});
```

I am currently on localhost. SO I am expecting the client ip address to be 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.request.ip`. It should work...

after testing i realized two things.

1. when behind a proxy, make sure the proxy is forwarding the clients ip using an x-forwarded-for header.
2. in theory 1. should be enough for `this.request.ip` to return the client ip, but it isn't. But after configuring my proxy, `this.request.header["x-forwarded-for"]` returns the client ip

test with this simple server:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function *(){
this.body = this.request.ip;
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hello tried it: `console.log(this.request.ip);`, returns undefined :/

Comment: are you happening to be behind a proxy? I'm using nginx here and i didn't get the cleint ip either. i had to do two things to get it right. In my servers nginx config i had to add `proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` and then in contrast to the documentation "x-forwarded-for" ist not supported, so i had to `this.request.header["x-forwarded-for"]`. i will update the answer acordingly...

Comment: Hello! Im currently only on localhost with everything. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: i've now just tried on localhost and `console.log(this.request.ip);` returns ::ffff:127.0.0.1 . What version of koa and node are you running?

Comment: Latest of both! 0.12 for node and koa ^1.0.0 (so latest)

Comment: mmh strange, i'm currently on a fresh ubuntu box with a fresh install of node  0.12 and koa 1.0.0, and it work s like a treat !?

Comment: I'll do this. I'll make a fresh project and run it see if that works. I'll update on what I do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90283/discussion-between-holger-will-and-karl-morrison).

Comment: Sitting on a bus currently, I'll join chat when I get back!